# How can I create a function to reserve meeting rooms and show which rooms are available?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to create that function to know what days the meeting rooms are available, so that it can show on the calendar the dates that the rooms are busy. That way it’s easier for someone to reserve the room.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you could create two lists: **Conference rooms and Room reservations.**

Conference rooms list has names of all existing rooms.

[image]

Room Reservations list stores bookings and contains three columns:

- **Conference room** (Lookup)
- **Reservation Date** (Date and Time)
- **Reserved by**(Person or Group).

[image]

Below article is to show you how to create step-by-step, hope it would help you.

[How to create SharePoint form for booking a meeting room.](https://plumsail.com/docs/forms-sp/examples/reservation-system.html)